# How to chat in CS:GO?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

How do I chat in **CS:GO**(Counter Strike:Global Offensive)? I have no idea which keys to press to chat.

Comment: A little bit of effort on your part with garner a much better reception.  Questions which don't display any, like this one, will gather downvotes based on that fact alone.  If you can take five minutes attempting to solve your problem before asking a question here, you'll get a more positive welcome.

Comment: I searched 'chat key in cs:go' in google and this is the first result: http://counterstrike.wikia.com/wiki/Controls

Comment: You probably don't find much in Google since everyone views the settings before creating a topic like this - or tries. However the solution is even in your link.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Messages**

The default key to chat in the Counter Strike series of games is <kbd>y</kbd>. This is *All Chat*, both teams will see what you can write here.

To write a message so that only your team can read it you want to use *Team Chat* which is started with <kbd>u</kbd>.

After pushing one of those keys, type your message and then push <kbd>enter</kbd> to send it.

---

**Voice Chat**

Pushing down the <kbd>k</kbd> key will allow you to communicate with a microphone. In a competitive match only at the end of the game will the opposing team be able to hear you.

---

**Console Commands**

Open the console using <kbd>`</kbd> and then you can use `say text` for *All Chat* or `say_team text` for *Team Chat*.

Comment: Regarding the voice chat see this [update](http://blog.counter-strike.net/index.php/2015/10/12687/):
_In official competitive matches, voice communications are now team-only in warmup and half-time, allowing players to discuss player roles and strategies._

Comment: @PhilippM Ah yes, I was aware of that, thanks for the prompt, i'll update the answer now, thanks :)

Comment: It is also worth noting that voice communication must be on in the game settings.

Comment: I usually rebind my voice chat key to the Left Alt key.

Answer (score 0):

push <kbd>Y</kbd> for chatting to your opponents. Voice chat was disabled after one patch in CS:GO because of too much hate and troll.